# Variables inside of Lambda Promise inside of async function w/ Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've wasted two days trying to find an answer to this. I have reduced my code to mostly pseudo code for simplicity.

I need to have an async function that is called as a trigger from an SQS queue. The code loops through the 10 SQS records sent and for each it calls Twilio and uses the promise format. I want to build an array during this process so that at the end I can do a batch write to DynamoDB.

**I can't figure out how to maintain/add to an array inside of the Twilio promise THEN that is readable outside/later.**

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
    let messages = [];
    
    //LOOP THROUGH SQS RECORDS
    event.Records.forEach(record => {
        //QUERY DYNAMO FOR DUPLICATES
        
        //IF NOT A DUPLICATE
        twilio.messages.create({
            body: event.text,
            to: event.phone,
            from: '+15005550006'
        })
        .then((message) => {
            //ADD MESSAGE TO STATUS SQS
            
            //CREATE ARRAY FOR ENTRY INTO DYNAMODB BATCH WRITE
            var item = {
                PutRequest: {
                  Item: {
                    'msgid': { S: msgid },
                    'text': { S: text },
                    'phone': { S: phone },
                    'date': { S: now }
                    }  
                }
            };
        });
        //END IF NOT A DUPLICATE
    });
    
    //BATCH WRITE TO DYNAMO OF ALL ITEMS IN MESSAGES ARRAY
};
```

**EDIT: This is the actual code based on suggestions. Nothing is logged on either console.log, not even the "message". Currently just trying to get anything from then to be returned in Promise.all. Actually need to return the messages array but trying to get SOMETHING to return.**

````
    let messages = [];
    
    var messagePromises = event.Records.map(record => { 
        var text = record.body;
        var phone = record.messageAttributes["phone"].stringValue;
        var msgserviceid = record.messageAttributes["msgserviceid"].stringValue;
        var userid = record.messageAttributes["userid"].stringValue;
        var credits = record.messageAttributes["credits"].stringValue;
        var item = [];
    
        var payload = {
            "phone": phone,
            "text": text,
            "msgserviceid": msgserviceid
        };
        
      return twilio.messages.create({
                body: text,
                to: phone,
                from: '+15005550006'
            }).then((message) => {
                var msgid = message.sid;

                var now = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
                
                var item = {
                    PutRequest: {
                      Item: {
                        'msgid': { S: msgid },
                        'text': { S: text },
                        'phone': { S: phone }
                        }  
                    }
                };
                
                messages.push(item);
                
                console.log("message", message);
                return message;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("error", error);
            });
    });
    
    Promise.all(messagePromises).then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
    });
};```
````

Comment: Put all the promises in an array. Then call `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them. In its `.then()` function you will be able to read all the array contents.

Comment: When I do this array messages is always empty when promise.all runs. Some sort of scope issue doing that.

Comment: Then you obviously did it wrong. Show what you tried.

Comment: Exactly what @Barmar said. You need to define empty array outside of forEach loop, push the promises into the array, Then call Promise.all() passing the array of promises as argument. It will resolve all the promises in the array.

Comment: I GET the concept. What you guys are recommending doesn't actually work. The messages array is empty when the promise.all runs but the messages array is correctly being filled inside the then.

Answer (score 1):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) all the promises into an array. And use [promise all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to know when they are done.

```
var messagePromises = event.Records.map(record => { 
  return twilio.messages
    .create({...})
    .then((message => {
       return {
         whatever: "you want to return";
       };
    });
});


Promise.all(messagePromises).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Basic idea....

```js
const twilio = {
  messages: {
    create: (foo) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
        window.setTimeout(() => resolve({
          [foo]: num
        }), num);
      });
    }
  }
};


const event = {
  Records: [{
    name: 'Foo'
  }, {
    name: 'bar'
  }, {
    name: 'Baz'
  }]
};

var messagePromises = event.Records.map(record => {
  return twilio.messages
    .create(record.name)
    .then((message) => {
      console.log(message);
      return message;
    });
});


Promise.all(messagePromises).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: OK, can you show me inside of this Promise.all how I access the array messages? When I've tried it's always empty even though I've proven it's being populated in the then.

Comment: It is an array of whatever you return from the last then

Comment: Can you show me an example? That was going to be my next question, are there any returns inside of the loop. Sounds like yes. So just return messages as the very last line of the Twilio then?

Comment: I do not know what you want to return so I have no clue. What ever you are expecting to process when everything is done is what you will return. Than when all the promises are complete, you will have an array of whatever you returned.

Comment: Original question clearly states that I'm trying to populate the messages array with items to later be batch inserted into DynamoDB. I tried your example and nothing is printed on console.log(values); This is the problem I've been experiencing for two days.

Comment: In your code,in your then, you return nothing.

Comment: I used this code even the console.log inside of the then does not happen.

Comment: I've added my updated code. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. So frustrating.

Comment: Are all the promises resolving? Might need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: I guess I don't know that answer. If this is helpful? The Twilio code worked before and I could console.log inside of the then and access message variable, etc. But after adding the suggesting code I, no console.logs happen even if they are the very first line of the then. Does that answer the question? I'm still new to this.

Comment: FYI, I added the allSettled command and still nothing.

Comment: If I remove the "return" before twilio.message... the console.logs all now works but the Promise.all value is undefined.

Comment: Actually, only the console.logs inside the Promise.all fire. The ones inside the twilio then do not fire.